# Image title both alingn. How to make each element aligned vertically?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page to list all the sponsors of a web site, with logo and the name of them. The problem is that I cannot align the titles because the logos having different height. The result is like that:

[image]

But I like to have the following result:

[image]

The HTML for each sponsor listing is this:

```
<div class="one_fourth">
    <a href="LINK_TO_SPONSOR">
        <img src="URL_TO_IMAGE" />
    </a>
    <h3>Sponsore Title</h3>
</div>
```

The CSS applied on my images is the following:

```
img
{
    display: block !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Is there a way to achive ther required result with CSS and if so, how ?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j67As/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insert a div that include your link and image and set the height to your div you can align your text
try this:

```
  <div class="one_fourth">
     <div class="img">
         <a href="LINK_TO_SPONSOR">
            <img src="URL_TO_IMAGE" />
         </a>
     </div>
     <h3>Sponsore Title</h3>
 </div>
```

And in your css add a class for that div setting the height max of the image

```
.img{
   height:100px; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dWDm/1/)

[**YOUR DEMO CORRECTED**](http://jsfiddle.net/j67As/2/)

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not have any effect. I have try this solution, and I cannot see any result :(. Anyway, thanks for ansering

Comment: again doesn't work. Ok I will show you what is my css. I am sorry, that I didn't show the CSS before

Comment: ok but if you see the demo that I have added you can see that this code works fine :) @MerianosNikos

Comment: In my case, when I apply the height 100% to my image, then I get the image destroyed

Comment: I don't see height:100% into your css, can you create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: This is what I am creating right now. I removed the height:100% because it is not part of my code, and also it didn't had any effect in my page.

Comment: try to apply my solution, insert a div with class img or what you want and apply mine css for that class like my jsfiddle, of you haven't other code this should work like my demo, if it doesn't work show your complete css and html to understand if something is wrong :) @MerianosNikos

Comment: you can now see what is my demo. I have create a fiddle.

Comment: And again, I have try by my self to use height : 100%; in the demo, and the images are getting distored :(

Comment: Ok I have added a new jsfiddle "your demo corretced" see that works fine :) @MerianosNikos

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to take the largest picture of your list and note down it's size.
Let's say for example, your biggest picture is 150x200 px.

Width: 150px;
Height: 200px;

Now, this will be the img div.

```
<div class="one_fourth">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="URL_TO_IMAGE" />
    </div>
    <a href="LINK_TO_SPONSOR">Link</a>    
</div>

#.one_forth{
 float: left; /* This is the most important thing here */
 "You could make the width 150px here and assign a width of 100% for .img. It varies with what you want.";
}

.img{
    display: block !important;
    width: 150px !important;
    height: 200px !important;
}

.img img{
    float: left;
}

.one_fourth a{
    "Your Style Here";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your responsponce, but that is not responsive solution to my problem. I need the image to be responsive, so fixed dimensions are not what do I need.

Comment: @MerianosNikos If you want the image to be responsive, you need the div one_fourth to be responsive. Now this will depend on your main div, the div in which you will put the images. In that case you use percentages. Lemme demonstrate that in an edit. ;)

Comment: @SabTeheCoder, tha div is already responsive. You can see my code in the demo I made on the fiddle. There is a link at the end of my question. Go to fiddle and play to see that your solution does not feet.

Comment: Alessandro wrote the fix before me. As you will see in his fix, it's inevitable to have a fixed height. The width can be a percentage, but height should be fixed.